# How to run a flask app on a remote server from a local system?

Tags: python, flask, remote-access, flask-restful

I'm able to run the flask app on the local system using `app.run()`. But when I try to run it on remote server using `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='81')` or `app.run(host='<remote ip>')`,both don't work. I want to know if something else has to be done.

Comment: Don't work means....error message? Can't access the webpage?

Comment: You can't run it that way on a remote server. The IP address **must** be local. If you want to use a port below 1024 you must be root. Using SSH you could run it locally and then forward it to the remote system using SSH's remote port tunnelling feature.

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? If you want the Flask app to run on a remote system, you must install it and run it on that system. If you are the system administrator, that means copying the application (and its dependencies) over and setting up a WSGI web server to run it on the server. If it's a shared host or an application server (like Heroku), the process will be different and documented by your web hosting provider.

Comment: Yes..when I do app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='81'), I cant access the webpage. And when I do app.run(host='<remote ip>'), I get a error saying "The requested address is not valid in its context".

Comment: Thank u Aaron D. I'l do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not from Flask,

The IP specified in `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` must be owned by your server.

If you want to launch Flask on remote server, deploy the code on that server using SSH and run it using a remote session.