# Launch Flask on remote server using SSH

Tags: python, ssh, flask, ubuntu-16.04

I'm currently trying to run my hello world app on local.  I want to be able to send a IP address of a friend and have their requests show on my local machine.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31889144/4180276) it seems that

```
The IP specified in app.run(host='0.0.0.0') must be owned by your server.

If you want to launch Flask on remote server use SSH.
```

Since I have a vps setup with ubuntu, and I'm on ubuntu, is there any way I can have him make the requests there and it forwards it to my local deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I have a vps setup with ubuntu, and I'm on ubuntu...

Why does your host OS matter? The VPS is an entirely separate machine.

> is there any way I can have him make the requests there and it forwards it to my local deployment?

If you have a **local** Flask instance that is *not on a VPS*, then you want to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), and you don't even need any parameter to `app.run()` since you can "expose" port 5000 directly via that tool.

Comment: is there a free alternative to ngrok? Since that appears to do exactly what I want

Comment: Umm it's free last time I checked

Answer (score 0):

Flask run on port 5000 in default. if you want your friend access your flask,

1. Open TCP/IP access at `{port_number}` in your ubuntu VPS. Example: 8088
2. Using `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port={port_number})` in python script (app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8088))
3. Check IP address of your VPS (not local IP). Example is 187.50.128.151
4. In your friend computer, using browser access *http://{your_vps_ip}:{port_number}* . Example: http://187.50.128.151:8088

Comment: I'm trying to have my friend access it but it be on my localhost, not the vps.  Since I don't have access to the wife/behind a firewall